# ¿Cómo quitar un Frame en pantalla al pasar a otro Frame?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Estoy trabajando con varias interfaces y unos de los pequeños inconvenientes con los que me he encontrado es que al oprimir el botón no se quita el JFrame que contiene dicho botón, el otro JFrame que invoco lo hace correctamente pero con el primero detrás de él.

```
  public Interfaz() {
    JFrame ventana = new JFrame("FRAME");
    ventana.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    ventana.setLayout(null);

    jButton1 = new JButton();
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("src/img/image.png");
    jButton1.setIcon(icon);
    jButton1.setBounds(15, 60, 100, 100);
    ventana.add(jButton1);

    ventana.setLocation(230, 55);
    ventana.setResizable(false);
    ventana.setVisible(true);
    ventana.setSize(580, 300);
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            new Ventana2();
          // ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

                dispose();


         }
    });
```

Encontré que el

```
  dispose();
```

es el que hace el trabajo de quitar el Frame pero esto no me sucede.
Aproximandamente así tengo el código, dentro tengo 4 botones. Agradecería la ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¿Ocurre alguna Exception? Si no ocurre ningún error entonces tu problema es que no estableces una **acción para cuando se cierre** el marco. Debes saber que el método `dispose()` actúa **solo si no hay** otras ventanas que dependan de ella.

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Además, veo que **no heredas** de `JFrame`, por lo que **¿quién llama a dispose()**? Deberías hacer:

```
ventana.dispose();
```

Comment: Comprendido, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

### Hay diferentes forma de hacerlo y aqui te presentare algunas de ellas:

Pero lo primero es utilizar el método .addWindowListerner para suscribirnos a los eventos que se produzcan en la ventana. Así, en el constructor de nuestro programa utilizaremos dicho método:

```
public CerrarVentana(){
```

addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {...});
}

El método asociado al cierre de la ventana es windowClosing. En él solo vamos a realizar un exit del sistema con System.exit.:

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
```

System.exit(0);
}

Así nuestro WindowAdapter quedaría de la siguiente forma para gestionar el cierre de una ventana con Java Swing:

```
public CerrarVentana(){
```

addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
     System.exit(0);
   }
 });

### }

Esto se hace dentro del codigo de la interfaz ya se en un evento o dentro de un boton.

### this.setVisible(false);